# Devoured while lost in time and space

Tags: eldritch-horror

One of our investigators *I1* was lost in time and space. Then, another investigator *I2* got a dark pact triggered, and the effect was "Another investigator of your choice is devoured".

1) Can *I1* be targeted by *I2*'s dark pact effect?

2) If 1), would *I2* actually be devoured? The text says that an investigator lost in time and space cannot be affected by anything.

We reason two things:

a) the wording means that *I2* could be targeted but not affected by the devouring

b) given the general theme and the unspoken rule that "if there are various interpretations of a rule in a cooperative game, choose the least helpful", it feels like a loophole that breaks the rules. Therefore, we chose another investigator to be devoured

We chose b). Did we choose "right"?

Comment: I1 cannot be devoured. I can bet my pants that they also cannot be chosen, but this is isn't official. I can answer when I get a clarification.

Comment: I think that it will read the same as "cannot be targeted or affected" but I'm not sure and haven't found any concise answer as of yet which explains it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you are right because of the unspoken rule of cooperative games. I could not find anything in the erratas apart from a reference to "move".

[image: Lost in Time and Space Condition card]

> You are unaffected by other game effects […]

This does imply that the investigator cannot have any effects at all. So they cannot be a target for anything at all: spells, Dark Pacts, etc…

This is again implied by the [errata](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/eldritch-horror/support/EH%20Errata%20&%20FAQ%202015-01-23.pdf), although it refers to "moves" and not other specific effects.

> Q. Can an investigator with a Lost in Time and Space Condition
>   be moved by another investigator using the Plumb the Void Spell?
>
> A. No. If an effect states that an investigator cannot move,
>   such as a Lost in Time and Space Condition or a Detained
>   Condition, that investigator cannot move on his own nor can
>   he be moved by any effect.

Comment: As you said, the unspoken rule of cooperative games should in principle mean we did it right. Neverhtless, what you mention in your answer is that the investigator cannot be *affected*, but there is no reference to wheter he could be *targeted*. For example, if you have the pocket watch you can be targeted by a delayed condition but not affected.

Comment: Indeed,  I could not find an official ruling on this.

Answer (score 1):

The investigator lost in time and space cannot be targeted by the dark pact's effect,
simply because he is not available for targeting.
*He is lost in time and space,
inaccessible to anyone.*

If I'm an ancient one, and let you choose another investigator to be devoured,
and you try to get clever on me and choose an investigator who is inaccessible,
I would just devour *you* out of spite.
So I think that's just how this should work.
Nice try, but no loopholes and wishful thinking.